# How to replace comma within partial string in Regular Expression for .NET?

Tags: regex

I need to find a proper Regular Expression to replace "," with "." within Json string. I'm working on .NET platform (c#)

The problem that I can't replace all ",", but only those contained in the " (double quote).

**Example.**

If I have this JSON string:

```
[{"Id":"1","Description":"XXXXXX","Value1":"9,21","Value2":"15,21"}]
```

the final result I need is this:

```
[{"Id":"1","Description":"XXXXXX","Value1":"9.21","Value2":"15.21"}]
```

You can notice Value1 and Value2, they became 9.21 (from 9,21) and 15.21 (from 15,21).

I can use Regular Expression server-side on .NET platform using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex or client side with Javascritp.

Thanks to all.
Regards

Comment: Which Language/Tool?

Comment: I'm using c# (.NET for server side ... javascript client side)...but regular expressions are not all equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a text editor, like Notepad++:

Search String: `(\:"\d+),(\d+")`
Replace string: `$1.$2`

Comment: Using C# server side in this way goes very well!
Thanks to all

            string input = datasource;
            string pattern = @"(\:""\d+),(\d+"")";
            string replacement = "$1.$2";
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
            string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);